# Spring Inject java.util.Properties or Map from @PropertySource via @Value

Tags: java, spring

I have the following in an @Configuration class

```
@PropertySource(name = "applicationProperties", value = {
        "classpath:application.properties",
        "classpath:${spring.profiles.active}.properties",
        "classpath:hibernate.properties",
"classpath:${spring.profiles.active}.hibernate.properties" })
```

I want to retrieve all the properties as a java.util.Properties object or filter it to a subset of properties by prefix using @Value.

```
//This works but only gives System.properties
@Value("#{systemProperties}")
private Properties systemProperties;

//I want to do this, but I can't find a way to make it work with Spring EL if there is a way.
@Value("#{application.Properties}")
private Properties appProperties;
```

I'm using a pure java configuration and I just need to get at the properties somehow that are configured by the @PropertySource. The Spring Environment only lets you get one property at a time.

In short, really what I want is all properties that are prefixed with hibernate.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see below link:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

if you're, or can, use Spring Boot, than you can do something like this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:config/hibernate.properties", prefix = "hibernate")
public class HibernateProperties {

    Properties datasource = new Properties();

    public Properties getDatasource() {
        return datasource;
    }

}
```

and the hibernate.properties file:

```
hibernate.datasource.initialize=false
hibernate.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
hibernate.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxx;DatabaseName=yyy
hibernate.datasource.username=user
hibernate.datasource.password=passwd
```

see that *hibernate* is prefix and *datasource* is the name of the properties object. so yo can call properties like datasource.get("initialize").

Than you can inject HibernateProperties class anywhere and call getProperties method to get the hibernate properties.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Not really what I wanted as I can't pass a HibernateSettings object into a method that takes a Properties object...